# Would FileInputStream reading /dev/hda1 effectively read the disk sectors

Tags: java, linux, disk, pattern-recognition

If I were to attach a FileInputStream to, say, /dev/hda1 and .read() a number of bytes, would this effectively read raw disk sectors?

Understand that I'm not interested in interpreting the data in the context of a filesystem, and I do not want to just duplicate it.

I want to read raw disk sectors and get the actual data as it resides on disk.

My reason is this - as a curiosity, I'm considering writing a cluster analysis pattern recognition program to analyze raw disk data.

Comment: If you want to do cluster analysis, then you __will__ have to interpret the data in the context of the filesystem of that partition.

Comment: Unsupervised machine learning will do the analysis of any parcel of data.  My analysis will be of example raw data, enough to write the cluster analysis algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will. A `Path` (or `File` with the old API) is just an abstract path. You can create `Paths.get("I don't exist")` (or `new File("I don't exist")` with the old API).

Since this is Unix, you can `open("/dev/hda1")`, hence you get a file descriptor with `read()` and `write()` (but don't) on it.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I wanted to bounce it off someone else.  Thanks

Comment: There is one limit with Java which can be seen as annoying there, it is that it can `mmap()` but in a limited fashion (ie, size)...